# ¿Cómo eliminar el sombreado del slide en un viewpager en Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Cuando se usa un `ViewPager` a la hora que se hace el gesto slide, cuando llegas a los topes inicio o fin, sale un sombreado, normalmente del color primario.

¿Hay alguna forma de eliminarlo o cambiar de color transparente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al `ViewPager` con el atributo `android:overScrollMode` se puede especificar que nunca se muestre la sombra ambos lados.

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
...
`android:overScrollMode="never"`
..
/>
```